# How can I perform the tempelate matching to get the direction of triangles?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to apply the template matching on the following image:
[image]

and my template images are:

[image]
[image]
[image]
Below is the code:

```
mask = cv2.imread("mask.png",0)        #source image

#tempelates
up = cv2.imread('up.png',0)
right = cv2.imread('right.png',0)     
left = cv2.imread('left.png',0)


res_up = cv2.matchTemplate(mask,up,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
res_right = cv2.matchTemplate(mask,right,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
res_left = cv2.matchTemplate(mask,left,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold=0.8
loc_up = np.where( res_up >= threshold)
loc_right = np.where( res_right>= threshold)
loc_left = np.where( res_left >= threshold)
print(loc_up)
print(loc_right)
print(loc_left)
```

My goal is to find the location(**centroid**) of each triangle and their direction (up/down/left/right) too. Since I am using the template match, for each direction separately, I think this should work. But I am getting an assertion error with this code regarding the shape of matrices. Is there any way I can use this method to know the location of triangles without error?

I am trying to solve it for the last day, yet have not been able to solve it.
Please help me with it, if it can be done!

**Edit1:** Here is the error I am getting on executing the above code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/Desktop/examples/tempelate_matching.py", line 48, in <module>
res_up = cv2.matchTemplate(mask,up,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) /tmp/pip-req-build-jr1ur_cf/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp:587: error:(-215:Assertion failed) corr.rows <= img.rows + templ.rows - 1 && corr.cols <= img.cols + templ.cols - 1 in function 'crossCorr'
```

**Edit2:** When I am trying to run the code on the source image and templates, I am not getting the error, and the code is working fine. Actually, I am not loading the image, its just that I have an image that I am converting into GRAY scale, and then masking it as follows:

```
img=env.camera_feed()
img=cv2.cvtColor(cv2.resize(img,(512,512)), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
mask=np.copy(img)
row,columns=mask.shape
for i in range(0,row):
    for j in range(0,columns):
        if ( mask[i][j]==26):
            mask[i][j]=255
        else: 
            mask[i][j]=0
```

After this, I get the same ***mask*** image as I have attached above. Which I am using for the template matching but getting error in this case.
Thank you!

Comment: Your code works on my PC (using as the left image, the rotated right image since you have uploaded the same image for both sides). Could you post the error you get and the version of Python and of OpenCV you are using?

Comment: Triangle has 3 edges, how do you decide the direction of triangle?

Comment: @LGrementieri, I have edited my question mentioning the error which I am getting. My python version is 3.8.5 and the OpenCV version is 4.5.1. Thank you for considering my doubt!

Comment: @Sociopath , as I have written the code, loc_up will have the location of all the triangles pointing in up direction, loc_right will have all the locations pointing in the right direction, loc_left will have all the locations pointing in the left direction. Isn't it?

Comment: The error message says what went wrong. Fix that. Assertion failed: corr.rows <= img.rows + templ.rows - 1 && corr.cols <= img.cols + templ.cols - 1.

Comment: @Sociopath regarding _"How do you decide the direction of triangle?"_ I'm guessing the **base** of each triangle is either horizontal or vertical (giving an up/down or left/right direction)...

Comment: @Sociopath: you don't have to worry about this. There are three templates and you will know which matches better.

Comment: This code works. Maybe you load by mistake images which are not those which you have here?

Comment: @Michael Sidoroff, yes this code is working. I have edited my question for more clarity.